# Como editar e carregar classe somente para um único elemento

Tags: angularjs

Possuo a seguinte estrutura HTML logo abaixo. Contudo, ao clicar em um dos "itens" a classe (edição) é exibida para ambos elementos. O que devo fazer para que isso ocorra somente no item clicado?

**Edição:**

Obs.: o `ng-click`, está dentro do loop `ng-repeat="item in items track by $index"`

Simulação no JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/19444/

```
<h4>Angular-xeditable Text (Bootstrap 3)</h4>
<form ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl" editable-form name="formulario">

  <!-- Texto I -->
  <a href="#" ng-click="formulario.$show()" ng-show="!formulario.$visible" editable-text="user.name">{{ user.name || 'empty' }}</a>
    <div class="buttons">
      <!-- buttons to submit / cancel form -->
      <span ng-show="formulario.$visible">
        <br/>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="formulario.$waiting">
          Save
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="formulario.$waiting" ng-click="formulario.$cancel()">
          Cancel
        </button>
      </span>
    </div>
    <br />

    <!-- Texto II -->
    <a href="#" ng-click="formulario.$show()" ng-show="!formulario.$visible" editable-text="user.name">{{ user.name || 'empty' }}</a>
    <div class="buttons">
      <!-- buttons to submit / cancel form -->
      <span ng-show="formulario.$visible">
        <br/>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="formulario.$waiting">
          Save
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="formulario.$waiting" ng-click="formulario.$cancel()">
          Cancel
        </button>
      </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["xeditable"]);

app.run(function(editableOptions) {
  editableOptions.theme = 'bs3';
});

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.user = {
    name: 'awesome user'
  };
});
```

Comment: Lucas, pelo que vi no seu código a ideia é ter uma lista de usuários e editar cada um deles, é isso?

Comment: Sim. @PedroCamaraJunior

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> O que devo fazer para que isso ocorra somente no item clicado?

Você deve identificar exclusivamente o item sob edição.

> O ng-click está dentro do loop `ng-repeat="item in items track by $index"`

Então você pode utilizar o `$index` como identificador exclusivo do item sob edição.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Versão modificada do seu código a seguir:

```js
var app = angular.module("app", ["xeditable"])
.run(function(editableOptions) {
  editableOptions.theme = 'bs3';
})
.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.targetIndex = -1;
  
  $scope.toggle = function(index){

    // Se o targetIndex atual for o mesmo do selecionado, então apague.
    // Caso contrário, salve o índice selecionado em targetIndex.

    $scope.targetIndex = ($scope.targetIndex == index ? null : index);
  }
  
  $scope.users = [
  {    name: 'awesome user 1'  }, 
  {    name: 'awesome user 2'  }, 
  ];
});
```

```css
div[ng-app] { margin: 50px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/dist/js/xeditable.js"></script>

<h4>Angular-xeditable Text (Bootstrap 3)</h4>

<form ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl" editable-form name="formulario">
  
  <div ng-repeat="user in users track by $index">
  <a href="#" ng-click="toggle($index)" ng-show="!(targetIndex == $index)" editable-text="user.name">{{ user.name || 'empty' }}</a>
  <input type='text' ng-model="user.name" ng-show="targetIndex == $index"/>
    <div class="buttons">
      <!-- buttons to submit / cancel form -->
      <span ng-show="targetIndex == $index">
        <br/>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="formulario.$waiting" ng-click="toggle($index)">
          Save
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="formulario.$waiting" ng-click="toggle($index)">
          Cancel
        </button>
      </span>
    </div>
  <br />
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

A solução para seu problema é bem simples, você só precisa ter uma propriedade `boolean` dentro de cada usuario, usaremos essa propriedade para mostrar ou ocultar o html de edição do usuário específico, veja meu exemplo:

#### Criei uma lista de usuários

```
$scope.usuarios = [{
    nome: 'João Batista'
  },
  {
    nome: 'Josefa Santos'
  }
];
```

Note que cada usuário possui apenas uma propriedade - `nome`, porém, para controlar se a div de cada usuário será exibida ou não, precisaremos de uma nova propriedade, vamos lá.

#### Vamos utilizar uma nova propriedade para cada usuário

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3" ng-show="usuario.isEditar">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="usuario.nome">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="salvar(usuario)">Salvar</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="usuario.isEditar = !usuario.isEditar">Cancelar</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Veja que criei um div que contém campo que vamos alterar e os botões responsáveis por "Salvar" e "Cancelar", e também utilizei no `ng-show` a propriedade `isEditar` do usuário - `ng-show="usuario.isEditar"`

Note que essa propriedade - `isEditar` - não foi declarada em lugar nehum no nosso controller, ou seja, estamos usando uma propriedade `undefined`, que para nossa alegria, para o `ng-show` será considerada como `false` e nossa div não será mostrada.

#### Agora, como vamos mostrar a div com os campos de edição?

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3" ng-show="!usuario.isEditar">
  {{ usuario.nome }} <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="usuario.isEditar= !usuario.isEditar">Editar</a>
</div>
```

Simples, criamos uma outra div com um input qualquer que altere o valor da propriedade `isEditar`do usuário para `true`. Para fazer isso, definimos o `ng-click` para inverter o valor da propriedade - `ng-click="usuario.isEditar= !usuario.isEditar"` - ou seja, quando for `false` alteraremos para `true`.

Note também que só mostro essa div quando o `isEditar` for `false` - `ng-show="!usuario.isEditar"`

Veja o exemplo abaixo e [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/PetrusStarken/NfPcH/19511/) o seu fiddle com as alterações.

```js
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp').controller('myCtrl', MyCtrl);

MyCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.usuarios = [{
      nome: 'João Batista'
    },
    {
      nome: 'Josefa Santos'
    }
  ];
  
  $scope.salvar = Salvar;
  
  function Salvar(usuario) {
    console.clear();
    console.log('Objeto usuário selecionado: ' + JSON.stringify(usuario));
    alert('Você salvou o usuário ' + usuario.nome);
    
    usuario.isEditar= !usuario.isEditar;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="usuario in usuarios">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3" ng-show="!usuario.isEditar">
        {{ usuario.nome }} <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="usuario.isEditar= !usuario.isEditar">Editar</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3" ng-show="usuario.isEditar">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="usuario.nome">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="salvar(usuario)">Salvar</button>
          <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="usuario.isEditar = !usuario.isEditar">Cancelar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Isso acontece porque os forms são gerenciados pela mesma propriedade, então que é modificada em um reflete no outro.

Então pra resolver essa questão em especifico separei as variáveis que gerenciam o estado do form.

#### HTML

```
<h4>Angular-xeditable Text (Bootstrap 3)</h4>
<form ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl" editable-form name="formulario">

  <!-- Texto I -->
  <a href="#" ng-click="show1()" ng-show="!form1Visible" editable-text="user.name">{{ user.name || 'empty' }}</a>
    <div class="buttons">
      <!-- buttons to submit / cancel form -->
      <span ng-show="form1Visible">
        <br/>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="formulario.$waiting">
          Save
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="formulario.$waiting" ng-click="cancel1()">
          Cancel
        </button>
      </span>
    </div>
    <br />

    <!-- Texto II -->
    <a href="#" ng-click="show2()" ng-show="!form2Visible" editable-text="user.name">{{ user.name || 'empty' }}</a>
    <div class="buttons">
      <!-- buttons to submit / cancel form -->
      <span ng-show="form2Visible">
        <br/>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="formulario.$waiting">
          Save
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="formulario.$waiting" ng-click="cancel2()">
          Cancel
        </button>
      </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

#### JS

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["xeditable"]);

app.run(function(editableOptions) {
  editableOptions.theme = 'bs3';
});

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.user = {
    name: 'awesome user'
  };
  $scope.form1Visible = false;
  $scope.form2Visible = false;

  $scope.show1 = function () {
    $scope.form1Visible = true;
  } 
  $scope.show2 = function () {
    $scope.form2Visible = true;
  } 
  $scope.cancel1 = function () {
    $scope.form1Visible = false;
  }
  $scope.cancel2 = function () {
    $scope.form2Visible = false;
  }
});
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/lucassilvax/NfPcH/19457/
Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Olá @LuKsSys, seria quase isso, porém esqueci de mencionar que essa estrutura está dentro do loop `ng-repeat="item in items track by $index"`